# Google Translate API vs PoEdit?

Tags: google-translate, po, poedit, google-translation-api

Recently, I find two ways to do translation for a web page:

1) Google Translate API

2) Poedit or create a PO, MO file

What are advantages or disadvantages of those two methods?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean automatic machine translation go with Google Translate.  If you mean you want professional translators to edit it you might want to look at Poedit or similar tools.

If you want quality with Google you will need to at least do post editing of the results.  With Poedit that is less of a problem in that it would be purely human.

If you are doing this for a client the Google Translate is not a good option, since you are sharing their information with Google and there might be a number of NDA related issues.